# Blinking lights detection and tracking

Tags: matlab, opencv, image-processing, computer-vision

I have a video of a set of blinking lights(LED in different frequencies) over a dark background and I want to detect LED , then track them in the video.
How can I do it if the number of LED is not given ?

Comment: are the LEDs stationary? Are they colored? Do you have a sample picture (even though you can't embed it in your question you can upload it to something like photshack,imgur,etc and post the link)? The more information you provide the more people can help you

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest colour tracking from a video, try [***this***](http://opencv-python-tutroals.readthedocs.org/en/latest/py_tutorials/py_imgproc/py_colorspaces/py_colorspaces.html#converting-colorspaces) link. There is example code and an explanation to how this is achieved in openCV.

The code is written in python, but once you have an idea of how it works, porting it to C++ shouldnt be too hard (Or you could do it in Python)

I think if you would like a more in-depth answer you should try providing more information in your question, it is rather vague. Explain more about what you are trying to achieve as an end goal, and hopefully people will be able to give you better information.